# Google Chrome 71 detection in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, detection

Since Google Chrome 71, using `!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;` to detect Google Chrome in javascript doesn't work anymore. It's pretty recent so I don't seem to find a good replacement yet.

Anybody know a good way to detect Google Chrome without `window.chrome.webstore`? Or are we stuck using `navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") !== -1` in the meantime?

Thanks!

Comment: Same issue here. Maybe a better question is, what changed in 71 that made it so this doesn't work anymore?  Was .webstore removed from the DOM?  Why?  Where is the documentation behind the change?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this:

var isChrome = /Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor);